# Difference between using [] and list() in Python when using with set() function

Tags: python, arrays

Could anyone tell me why this function work:

```
def findDisappearedNumbers(self, nums):
    return list(set(range(1,len(nums)+1)) - set(nums))
```

but this function doesn't work:

```
def findDisappearedNums(self, nums): 
    return [set(range(1, len(nums)+1)) - set(nums)]
```

I would like to use [] instead of list() because [] has a better performance, but using [] with set() function would give me an error while list() with set() function works fine. Thanks.

```
>>> from timeit import timeit
>>> timeit("[]")
0.040084982867934334
>>> timeit("list()")
0.17704233359267718enter code here
```

Comment: A function call is always slower than a literal expression. What's the error with `list()`?

Answer (score 4):

They do different things.

`list(set('abc'))` gives you a list with three elements: `'a'`, `'b'`, and `'c'` in it.

`[set('abc')]` gives you a list with exactly one element: the `set`.

Answer (score 3):

It's not quite the same.  When you use `[]` as you are using it, you get a list with a single element, in this case a set of numbers.  When you cast it with `list()`, you're saying 'take all the elements of the set and make a list out of them'.  You can do this with list comprehensions if you like, by doing:

```
[x for x in set(range(1, len(nums)+1)) - set(nums)]
```

but I think most pythonistas would just use `list()` in a case like this.

Answer (score 1):

`list()` and `[]` do different things. `list` takes an iterable, and puts all of its elements into a list. `[]` takes individual elements, and puts them into a list.

Hence, `list(iterable)` will get you a list of the same length (and elements) as the iterable. `[iterable]` will make a list of length 1, where the only element in the list is the iterable, which in turn may contain multiple elements.

Answer (score 0):

Like what the other answers says. `set(range(10))` is different from `list(set(10))`.

```
>>> set(range(10))
# Will create a set of unique numbers, obviously, from 1 to 9
{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}
```

However,

```
>>> list(set(range(10))) # Or: [k for k in set(range(10))]
# Will create a list of one element, which is the set of the unique numbers
# between 1 and 9
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

But, in your question, your benchmark isn't fully correct. You said that using `list()` to convert the `set()` to a list is slower than using `[]`.

This kind of informations are not correct, even though your benchmark when creating an empty list is correct (creating an empty list using the constructor `list()` is slower than using `[]`).

But, there is another benchmark using all form of 'tricks', that i know to convert a set into a list:

**Empty lists:**

```
>>> timeit("[]")
0.05085730400242028
>>> timeit("list()")
0.18752098699769704
```

**Converting a `set()` into a `list`:**

```
>>> timeit("list(set(range(10)))")
1.9528166900017823
>>> timeit("set(range(10)).__reduce__()[1][0]")
2.8951575540013437
>>> timeit("[k for k in set(range(10))]")
2.771309465999366
```

Well, as you can see, using `list()` is more faster than using `[]`, also using `list()` is more faster than using `set().__reduce__()`.

**PS:** I'm using a 32bit OS with 2GB of RAM.